# Rename specific line in multiple files

Tags: awk, sed

My question is:
I have multiple files in a folder, and within each of these I would like to change specific lines. For example:

file_1.fasta contains:

```
>remove__c_0000234
ACTG
>remove__c_0000235
CGTA
```

file_2.fasta contains:

```
>remove__c_0000345
CCTA
>remove__c_0000431
```

...

I would like to remove the `>remove__` part from each file in that folder. How can I do that with a one-liner on Linux?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough: `sed -s -i 's/>remove__//g' *.fasta`

The longer form would be `sed --separate --in-place 's/>remove__//g' *.fasta`, where `-s` tells sed to treat the input as separate files and not as a continous stream. and `-i` makes it work in the files directly, instead of showing the result on stdout.

Looking at your example files after executing above command (the headers won't appear in the files):

```
$ more *.fasta | cat
::::::::::::::
file_1.fasta
::::::::::::::
c_0000234
ACTG
c_0000235
CGTA
::::::::::::::
file_2.fasta
::::::::::::::
c_0000345
CCTA
c_000043
```

Comment: Thank you markgraf for the fast reply. It worked :)

Comment: And what if after >remove__ there is a number in each file? For example: in file_1 >remove_1__c_0023 and in file_2: >remove_2__c_0021?

Comment: I found the solution: for file in /path/to/folder/*.fasta; do sed -i 's/>remove__[0-9]*_//g' "$file"; done